# Xbox Series S: PIN protect adult games and apps (the console is usually used by toddlers without their own Xbox account)

Tags: xbox-series-x-series-s

I really love this about Edge browser on Xbox Series S

> Enable Ask for my PIN to launch Microsoft Edge to protect your
> browsing experience on console.

Can I also PIN protect other apps and games? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you’re looking for is called the “Guest Pin”, which if enabled is required before launching games and apps if no one is signed in.

You can find it under **Settings > System > Access restrictions**

https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/family-online-safety/passkey-guest-key/setup-guest-key-limits

The guest pin is also useful if (like me) you have older children with time limits set up, because it prevents them from getting around the time limits by not signing into their own accounts.